# How to maintain correlation among array elements in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a `student collection` in mongo as below:

```
{
"_id":1,
"name":"John"
"address":[
        {
         "country":"US",
         "city":"Newyork"
        },
        {
         "country":"Canada",
         "city":"Ottawa"
        }
        ]
}
```

Now,the problem is that this `student` will satisfy a query with filter :

```
"address.country"="US" && "address.city"="Ottawa"
```

So, the `correlation between country and city is lost` here. The above student should have satisfied queries with following filters only:

```
->    "address.country"="US" && "address.city"="Newyork"
->    "address.country"="Canada" && "address.city"="Ottawa"
```

How can I maintain or preserve such correlation in mongo ?

Comment: Try [elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents)

```
db.students.find(
   { address: { $elemMatch: { country: "US", city: "Newyork" } } }
)
```